# UserSecrets not working with ModularStartup

Tags: servicestack

I am using 5.7.1 and when I use modular startup UserSecrets are not added to the IConfiguration collection.

This works:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

This doesn't:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseModularStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

appSettings.json gets added to both but secrets only are getting added to standard startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because the surrogate Modular Startup class that's used is defined in a different assembly and the implicit behavior is to only try register secrets in the `Startup` assembly.

You can try [registering UserSecrets explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#access-a-secret):

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx,config) => config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>())
        .UseModularStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

Comment: `'IWebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddUserSecrets'`  I tried adding  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets` and `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets` nuget packages but same message.

Comment: @Guerrilla I've just re-read the docs, the ext method is on `ConfigurationBuilder` not `IHostBuilder`, inspecting the source code shows you should be able to customize the configuration in `ConfigureAppConfiguration()`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the docs confused me as it was using different class.  It is working now :)